# How does binary file writing order structures?

Tags: c++, struct, io, binary

So I'm writing a program to write a structure to a file and then another to read said structure. If the struct was:

```
struct MODEL
{
    FLOAT X, Y, Z;
    D3DXVECTOR3 Normal;
    FLOAT U, V;
};

struct RETURNTYPE
{
    float vsize, isize;
    MODEL* model;
    DWORD* index;
}; //actual out structure
```

would the techniques on http://courses.cs.vt.edu/cs2604/fall01/binio.html mean it would be written in that order and would it be read in that order?

Comment: If you have resources you're using that are necessary to answer the question, please copy the relevant parts into your question. Questions on SO are meant to be self-contained so that they continue to be useful and relevant even if your link expires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not necessarily, no. The examples given the page (at least the bits I read/skimmed over) are dangerous because you're dumping raw memory to disk, then reading it back. This is not good practice.

In short: the C and C++ language specifications do not stipulate the memory layout of structs, indeed there are proprietary language extensions that allow the developer to define memory alignment, padding, and other details of structs, for this reason the code as given is not portable between compilers (or even necessarily versions of the same compiler, if any behavior were to be changed).

Also, the example given only works for structs that contain value-types; pointer-values or reference-types have no meaning when serialized from memory to disk, if you have a struct like this:

```
struct Foo {
    char* someString;
};
```

Then it will be serialized to disk as an integer that could be 32-bit or 64-bits long depending on the platform, and that integer means nothing because a memory address doesn't mean anything on disk, especially after the process that wrote it has ended.

Here's another gotcha: on 68k and PowerPC (and other big-endian platforms), integers will be byte-reversed compared to x86/x64 which are little-endian, making the exact same C/C++ code generate incompatible files on different platforms. This is why many files weren't compatible between Mac OS and the IBM PC/Windows in the 1990s, you needed to invest in 'converter software' that knew which fields to re-set the byte-order to.

Anyway, the best way to write complex-types to disk is to write your own serialization method, which has other benefits, such as self-documentating the file-format. Like so:

```
struct Foo {
    private:
    int foo;
    public:
    void serialize(ostream& stream) {
        stream.write( htonl( foo ) ); // htonl converts integers to big-endian order
    }
    void deserialize(istream& stream) {
        stream.read( &foo, sizeof(int) );
        foo = ntohl( foo ); // convert from big-endian back to native byte-order
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Do you know of any resources that further go into depth on the serialization stuff?